# How can I fix the code so it prints out the sum of each pair?

Tags: c++, algorithm

> N pairs of numbers are given. Print the sum of each pair.
>
> The first line of the standard input is N (1≤N≤100000). The following N lines contain exactly two integers, separated by a space whose absolute values are less than 1,000,000,000.
>
> INPUT
>
> ```
> 2
> 1 1
> -1 0
> ```
>
> OUTPUT:
>
> ```
> 2
> -1
> ```

I've written this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned short int n;
  long int n2,n3, rez;
  rez=0;


  //Uneseno broj linija:
  cin>>n;

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    if(rez==0)
    {
    cin>>n2>>n3;
    rez=n2+n3;
    cout<<rez<<endl;
    }
    rez=0;
  }


return 0;
}
```

Now this would be perfectly fine, but I don't get required output.
I can't think of the other idea, because I don't know how many exactly of N's will be there, so I can't predict numbers of variables that I should create, which will store result of two numbers entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is almost working. All you need to do is make `n` larger. An `unsigned short` caps out at 65,535. Bump it up to an `unsigned int` so it can handle values up to 100,000.

Aside from that, the `rez` variable isn't needed. You can delete it.

Also, there's no need to store all the numbers first and then calculate the sums afterwards. Calculating them as you go will work just fine. `cin` and `cout` are independent streams of data and it's fine to interlace reads and writes. Avoid storing them in a vector or an array as that just chews up a lot of memory for no benefit.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  unsigned n;
  std::cin >> n;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    long n2, n3;
    std::cin >> n2 >> n3;
    std::cout << (n2 + n3) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Style notes:

- [Avoid `using namespace std;`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice/). It's better to write out `std::` everywhere.
- I moved `n2` and `n3` inside the loop. Try to declare variables as late as possible to limit their scope rather than declaring them all at the top of the function. It makes it obvious that they're only used inside the loop and that their values don't persist across iterations.
- Add some whitespace around operators. Cramming everything together is hard to read.

Answer (score -3):

I have changed some of the numeric types you've used. Does this work?

```
int main()
{
    vector<long long int> results;
    unsigned long int n;
    long long int n2, n3, rez;

    cin >> n;

    for (unsigned long int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> n2 >> n3;
        rez = n2 + n3;
        results.push_back(rez);
        rez = 0;
    }

    for (auto result: results)
    {
        cout << result << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to put the results in a vector. It's a waste of memory.

Comment: It's a way to iterate over a vector, without explicitly using iterators. It's available in c++17.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'm aware, it was just a quick prototype, Pshyotic needs something that works, and it apparently does.